# Keep child element's font-size unaffected by root element's font-size

Tags: html, css, fonts, size, font-size

I'm creating a one-page layout which uses a few aspect-ratio media queries to prevent scrolling.

One problem I'm having though is I want the whole site to scale smaller once a certain media query is triggered: This is relatively easy because all of my units are defined as `rems`, all I had to do was change the root `html` element's `font-size` to a relative one like `1.75vw` which makes all my `rem` defined elements scale smaller with the windows width.

However, I want one element to ignore this and stay it's original size. How can I have the `footer` element sort of "break out" of the `html`s font size and stay a constant size as in default behavior? Ideas?

```css
/* ///////////////////////////////// INITIAL /////////////////////////////// */
html {
  color: #777;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
code {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -0.075rem;
}

/* /////////////////////////////////// VIEWPORT //////////////////////////// */

/* / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / ASPECT RAITOS / / / / / / / / / / / / / / */
@media ( max-aspect-ratio: 3/1 ) {
  html {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 1.75vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrp">

      <main>
        <p>Regular paragraph text</p> 
      </main>
      
      <footer>        
        <p>
          I don't want the <code>font-size</code> of this paragrah to be
          affected by the <code>html</code> element's <code>font-size</code>.
          I want this element's <code>font-size</code> to stay at 16 pixels
          at all times as the page is resized.
        </p>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: isn't the answer already in your question? You use `rem` to stay anchored to the root element. You have one element you don't want anchored to the root element: don't use `rem` for that element.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I thought using any unit on the `footer` element wouldn't work because it is still nested inside an `html` element which has an explicit `font-size`.

Comment: "The most specific rule wins" for CSS. Give your footer its own size and that size "wins".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deifine the **css** `font-size` for `footer` element and **it will be unaffected**.

```
footer{ font-size:16px;}
```

> Here is a working example:

```css
/* ///////////////////////////////// INITIAL /////////////////////////////// */
html {
  color: #777;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
code {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -0.075rem;
}
footer { font-size:16px ;}
/* /////////////////////////////////// VIEWPORT //////////////////////////// */

/* / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / ASPECT RAITOS / / / / / / / / / / / / / / */
@media ( max-aspect-ratio: 3/1 ) {
  html {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 1.75vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrp">

      <main>
        <p>Regular paragraph text</p> 
      </main>
      
      <footer>        
        <p>
          I don't want the <code>font-size</code> of this paragrah to be
          affected by the <code>html</code> element's <code>font-size</code>.
          I want this element's <code>font-size</code> to stay at 16 pixels
          at all times as the page is resized.
        </p>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I'd suggest simply overriding the `font-size` property in the `footer`.

**Example:**

```
/* / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / ASPECT RAITOS / / / / / / / / / / / / / / */
@media ( max-aspect-ratio: 3/1 ) {
  html {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 1.75vw;
  }

  footer{
    font-size: 1vw;
  }
}
```

That way the `footer` won't be affected by the `font-size` defined in the `html` CSS rule.